# How to find the subtypes of an abstract type in Julia Base?

Tags: julia

For example, suppose I write a function for `AbstractFloat`, I want to know the impact of this method definition, how do I check all the subtypes of `AbstractFloat` in Base?

Comment: you just said the answer "subtypes of AbstractFloat": `subtypes(AbstractFloat)`

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel shame for not knowing this. Would you mind making it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you were looking for [`subtypes`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.subtypes):

> Return a list of immediate subtypes of DataType T. Note that all currently loaded subtypes are included, including those not visible in the current module.

```
julia> subtypes(AbstractFloat)
4-element Array{Union{DataType, UnionAll},1}:
 BigFloat
 Float16 
 Float32 
 Float64
```

But interestingly, there is only one in `Base`:

```
julia> subtypes(Base, AbstractFloat)
1-element Array{Union{DataType, UnionAll},1}:
 BigFloat
```

BTW, there is a nice recipe in [PlotRecipes.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotRecipes.jl) for visualizing the type tree:
[image]

Comment: The rest are `Core` no?

Comment: @AlexanderMorley yes

Answer (score 2):

You could use typeof and methodswith to help find answer to similar question in future:

```
julia> methodswith(typeof(AbstractFloat))
13-element Array{Method,1}:
 deserialize(s::AbstractSerializer, t::DataType) in Base.Serializer at     serialize.jl:1045
 dump(io::IO, x::DataType) in Base at show.jl:1304                                                       
 dump(io::IO, x::DataType, n::Int64, indent) in Base at show.jl:1209                                     
 eltype(t::DataType) in Base at array.jl:46                                                              
 fieldname(t::DataType, i::Integer) in Base at reflection.jl:120                                         
 fieldnames(t::DataType) in Base at reflection.jl:143                                                    
 fieldoffset(x::DataType, idx::Integer) in Base at reflection.jl:335                                     
 isbits(t::DataType) in Base at reflection.jl:233                                                        
 serialize(s::AbstractSerializer, t::DataType) in Base.Serializer at serialize.jl:538                    
 show(io::IO, x::DataType) in Base at show.jl:211                                                        
 subtypes(m::Module, x::Union{DataType, UnionAll}) in Base at reflection.jl:437                          
 subtypes(x::Union{DataType, UnionAll}) in Base at reflection.jl:460                                     
 supertype(T::DataType) in Base at operators.jl:41
```

I am pythonista so I added `macro dir(a) :(methodswith(typeof($a))) end` into `~/.juliarc.jl` and now I could write:

```
julia> @dir AbstractFloat
```

Comment: the macro will always return the same result for any DataType, I guess you mean ‘methodswith(certain type)’ or ‘methodswith(typeof(certain instance))’, seems like a typo?

Comment: @Gnimuc yes I plan to use it for instances. For example `@dir ""` . Macro is not very clever but I use to use `methodswith(typeof(something))` pretty often. Maybe it will change because I am still newbie. And for example this is pretty useless (in this version of macro) -> `@dir [1.0]`. It's because `methodswith(Array{Float64,1})` return `0-element Array{Method,1}`! And btw methodswith(Array{Float64,1}, true) return 1078-element Array! I would probably need to rewrite it completely (some kind of DataFrame come to mind :).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, this function needs to be connected from the InteractiveUtils package.
See [SOF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62012171/julia-undefvarerror-subtypes-not-defined) for details.